# Weighted Non-negative Least Square Linear Regression in python

Tags: python, scipy, linear-regression, statsmodels

I know there is an [weighted OLS solver](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.WLS.html), and a 
[constrained OLS solver](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html).

Is there a routine that combines the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simulate OLS weighting by modifying the *X* and *y* inputs. In OLS, you solve *β* for

*X<sup>t</sup>X β = X<sup>t</sup>y*.

In Weighted OLS, [you solve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Weighted_least_squares)

*X<sup>t</sup>X W β = X<sup>t</sup> W y*.

where *W* is a diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries. It follows that *W<sup>0.5</sup>* exists, and you can formulate this as

*(X W<sup>0.5</sup>)<sup>t</sup>(XW<sup>0.5</sup>)  β = (X W<sup>0.5</sup>)<sup>t</sup>(XW<sup>0.5</sup>)  y*,

which is an OLS problem with *X W<sup>0.5</sup>* and *W<sup>0.5</sup> y*.

---

Consequently, by modifying the inputs, you can use a non-negative constraint system which does not directly recognize weights.

Comment: Thanks. I did think about this, but with the constant term, it would not be equivalent, would it?

Comment: @RAY Where in the above is there an assumption that one of the columns of *X* is not a constant 1?

Comment: You are right. I think my comment above came from a failure to recognize the complete equivalency of the with and without constant regressions. In my mind I was also looking to weight the squares of errors rather than the observations but realized that I could always weight the observations using sqrt of my intended weights